# If the covenant of Christ only permits men to call God "Father" (Galatians 4:5, Ephesians 1:5) - How can Isaiah call YHVH "Father" under Mosaic Law?

Tags: isaiah, names-of-god, covenant

If the covenant of Christ only permits men to call God "Father" (Galatians 4:5, Ephesians 1:5) - How can the prophet Isaiah call YHVH "Father" under Mosaic Law?

**[Yeshayahu יְשַׁעְיָ֣הוּ | Isaiah 63:16]** "For You are our father, for Avraham did not know us, neither did Yisrael recognize us; **You, YHVH, are our Father**; our redeemer of old is your name." (כִּֽי־אַתָּ֣ה אָבִ֔ינוּ כִּ֚י אַבְרָהָם֙ לֹ֣א יְדָעָ֔נוּ וְיִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל לֹ֣א יַכִּירָ֑נוּ אַתָּ֚ה יְהֹוָה֙ אָבִ֔ינוּ גֹּֽאֲלֵ֥נוּ מֵֽעוֹלָ֖ם שְׁמֶֽךָ)

- Yeshayahu יְשַׁעְיָ֣הוּ never knew Jesus of Nazareth, but recognized יְהֹוָה֙ YHVH as Avinu אָבִ֔ינוּ "Our-Father".

**Why was a recognition of Jesus as Christ not required for Israelites like Yeshayahu יְשַׁעְיָ֣הוּ "Isaiah" to call YHVH their Father, under Mosaic Law?**

Comment: See Isa 9:6 for the example of where Messiah will be called "everlasting father".

Comment: *If the covenant of Christ **only*** - I think it should read *If **only** the covenant of Christ*.

Comment: It's not obvious what "only" applies to.  As it is now, I first read it as "only permits" (meaning "doesn't require"). It could also mean "only men (not women)", or "only God" (meaning not a priest), etc.  When you ask the question out loud, which word or phrase do you stress to indicate what the "only" applies to?

Comment: I don't see how any of this follows. Galatians 4:5 and Ephesians 1:5 do not say that only the covenant of Christ permits men to call God father.

Answer (score 2):

You are conflating ‘man’ with ‘nations’….

**EXODUS 4:22** *Then you shall say to Pharaoh, ‘Thus says the Lord: “Israel is My son, My firstborn.*

When Isaiah says … “*For You are our father*”, he is speaking on behalf of the people [nation]. A *prophet* speaks to ‘the people’ on behalf of God *and* to God on behalf of ‘the *people*’.

**GAL 4:6** *And because you are sons* [snip]

Where as in Galatians Paul is saying that *they themselves* [believers] are sons.

Answer (score -1):

Heres some notes.

Verse 16
Thou art our Father. Reference to Pentateuch (Deuteronomy 32:6 ).

Father. A rare word in this connection. Compare Isaiah 64:8 .

Redeemer. See note on Isaiah 60:16 .

Bullingers notes.